# PHP - Parse XML

Tags: php, parsing

I am attempting to learn APIs and trying with the Amazon's AWSECommerceService. Using the XML below, I am trying to parse out specific values. In particular, I would like to get a value that is within a nest such as the number with . I thought I could do this with PHP SimpleXML but I am having a hard time doing this. Why won't this code work?

```
<?php
$xml=simplexml_load_file("test.xml") or die("Error: Cannot create object");
echo $xml->ItemLookupResponse[0]->Offers->TotalOffers . "<br>";
?>
```

Comment: What's the output?

Comment: Blank - absolutely no output :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your simpleXML root is `ItemLookupResponse` so change

```
echo $xml->ItemLookupResponse[0]->Offers->TotalOffers . "<br>";
```

into

```
echo $xml->Items->Item->Offers->TotalOffers . "<br>";
```

Comment: do you know if there is any way to get assign all the variables to a node? Similar to how JSON has extract function?